# Nested Grid Example - Different Columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using the latest version of ui-grid [ui-grid.info](http://ui-grid.info/).

What is the best way to handle nested grids with the possibility of the nested child grid having different columns then the parent row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expandable Grids are probably the best approach. I have not tried this for more than one level but they work pretty well.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

Comment: Thanks!  I added the expanded grid and it worked perfect

Comment: Anyone have success or an example or adding more than one level to the grid?

Comment: @jeremythamm have you find the solution for multi level to the ui grid

Comment: No not yet, I do not believe its supported